# How to retrieve the week number of the year starting at 1 Jan?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, datetime

So I have a shell script which returns me the week number using an SQL query :

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/01/2022','DD/MM/YYYY'),'fmWW') as WEEK from dual;
```

This query returns 1. (Starting at 1st Jan)

Python code:
I have tried the following however it returns 52 rather than 1 :

```
week=datetime.date(2022,1,1).isocalendar()[1]
```

Week starting from Mon-Sun

Is there another way in which I can get the week number of year based on starting at 1st Jan so
I get 1 for 01/01/2022?

Required output:

```
Week ending Jan 2 2022 = 1
Week ending Jan 9 2022 = 2
Week ending Jan 16 2022 = 3
```

Comment: The ISO definition for week 1 is the week with the first Thursday in it. Using the ISO week number may give unexpected results near the start and end of a year.

Comment: What is it your definition of week number? ISO week is nearly standard but you may use ISO week year (so on 1st January 2022 you may still be in 2021 W52). There are many other week definition, but you should tell us which you are using (e.g. which day start the week. Same week can have two different number in two different years?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have added some example dates. I am trying to do the same as using ww format in sql ( number of the year starting at 1 Jan).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Oracle?)

Comment: @jarlh oracle 18

Comment: Note that your Oracle SQL query will return week 1 for a whole 7 days, i.e. week 2 starts at 08/01/2022.

Comment: @jarlh ah didnt notice that. How would I be able to get the week of year based on a week being monday-sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way in which I can get the week number of year based on starting at 1st Jan so I get 1 for 01/01/2022?

You can use, for a given date `dt`, as you said in the question:

```sql
TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmWW')
```

or can calculate it using:

```sql
FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(dt, 'YY'))/7)+1
```

or, to match the python code, can get the ISO week using:

```sql
TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmIW')
```

Or, if you want to start counting the week from the 1st January and change weeks on a Monday then:

```sql
FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(TRUNC(dt, 'YY'), 'IW'))/7)+1
```

Then the query:

```sql
WITH sample_dates (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-12-30' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 40
)
SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmWW') AS week,
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmIW') AS isoweek,
       FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(dt, 'YY'))/7)+1 AS weekfromyearstart,
       FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(TRUNC(dt, 'YY'), 'IW'))/7)+1 AS montosunweekfromyearstart
FROM   sample_dates
```

Outputs:

> | DT | WEEK | ISOWEEK | WEEKFROMYEARSTART | MONTOSUNWEEKFROMYEARSTART |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-12-30 | 52 | 52 | 52 | 53 |
> | 2021-12-31 | 53 | 52 | 53 | 53 |
> | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 52 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 52 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2022-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-07 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-08 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-09 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-10 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-11 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-12 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-13 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-14 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-15 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-16 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-17 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-18 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-19 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-20 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-21 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-22 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-23 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-24 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-25 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-26 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-27 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-28 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-29 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-30 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-31 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-01 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-02 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-03 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-04 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-05 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-06 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
> | 2022-02-07 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a410d93773fda9dc35643d96ca1a20d)*

---

If you want a Python function then:

```py
import datetime

def week_from_year_start(dt: datetime.date) -> int:
     year_start = dt.replace(month=1, day=1)
     return int((dt - year_start).days/7) + 1
```

or:

```py
def mon_sun_week_from_year_start(dt: datetime.date) -> int:
     year_start = dt.replace(month=1, day=1)
     week_start = year_start - datetime.timedelta(days=year_start.weekday())
     return int((dt - week_start).days/7) + 1
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants a week to be Monday to Sunday, i.e. Jan 3 2022 should be first day of week 2.

Comment: @jarlh I was just updating with that.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for this. If there is no equilant way of getting the week number from WEEKFROMYEARSTART in python then I may aswell use the iso format.

Comment: @Carlson Added python functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using isocalendar(), so ISO week definition: so every week has one single number (which should be used with the year): in such case, you are still in the last week of 2021.

I do not find a simple solution, but you can use this ugly trick:

```
 this_date = datetime.date(2022,1,1)
 week = int(this_date.strftime("%W")) + int(this_date.weekday() != 0)
```

How it work: python has three weeks definitions:

> **%U**: Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero-padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.
>
> **%W**: Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a zero-padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.
>
> **%V**: ISO 8601 week as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4.

`%W` seems a good candidate, but it starts with 0 until the first Monday.

So we may add `+1`, but then it fails when the first day of year is Monday. The second part is just a test for Monday. Remember that an the integer of a boolean is 0 for `False` and 1 for `True`. You may prefer to use an `if else` operator.

If you prefer to have weeks numbered from Sunday, just replace `%W` with `%U`.